# How to restore revision history after folder was moved incorrectly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Everything was done in the following steps:

1. A new folder as a target location was created in the repository
2. The original folder was copied to the target location in a local copy
3. Changes in the target folder were committed from the local copy to the repository
4. The original folder was deleted and it was committed.

In the end we have the original folder in a new location within the same repository, but without its revision history.

Is there a way to restore its revision history?

Comment: Did you use regular copy of svn copy?

Comment: I doubt we could have this problem if we used svn copy/move utility

Comment: If you have used `svn copy`, then revision history will also get copied.

Comment: You could create a patch file with the changes done to your wrongly copied folder. Then do a reverse merge to restore the original folder and next apply the patch. Then you should have the history of the original folder and the changes done to the copied folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did not use `svn copy` and just copied and pasted manually.
What would work, would be to merge back before the copy and then use the `svn copy` command.